# Zip folder from FTP

Tags: php

```
<?

$ftp_server = "name.info";
$ftp_user = "user";
$ftp_pass = "pass";

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) 
{
    ftp_chdir($conn_id, 'public_html/');
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '-la .');
    print_r($contents);
    foreach($contents as $line){
      $file = preg_split('@\s+@', trim($line));
      $name = $file[8];
      $size = $file[4];
      $mode = $file[0];
      if(substr($mode, 0, 1) == '-'){
        //file
        $fd = fopen('d/'.$name, 'w');
        ftp_fget ($conn_id, $fd, $name, FTP_BINARY);
        fclose($fd);
      }else{
        //dir
      }
    }
}
else
    die ("Couldn't connect as $ftp_user\n");

?>
```

I want to get all public_html folder. It would be perfect if I could zip it. I tried to write something, but it just doesn't copy those files. What am I missing?

Comment: @thetaiko: It doesn't copy files to my directory.

Comment: @hey...right.  What, specifically, doesn't work.  The connect?  The login?  The fget?  There are a ton of functions here which return a boolean on success or failure.

Comment: If my solution helps, please accept it as answer. If not, please comment and let me know why. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the code I use on slow FTP Servers: It creates a zip file and then it takes me 5 min to copy it to my local computer (depending of the internet speed connection and zipped file size)

```
<?php 

$archive = "2012.zip";
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
exec( "zip -r $archive $directory");

 ?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux and not limited by php's safe_mode (use phpinfo() to find out) then you could simply use exec() to run the zip command from a shell like:

```
<?
exec("zip -R public_html.zip /home/username/public_html",$output);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: just to clarify, if you have FTP access then you can upload this statement as a standalone script and call it through a browser.